# YouTube API video doesn't start in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api

I am trying to add a YouTube Video Player in a fragment, inside an activity with multiple tabs. So far, I have managed to run the code, but I cannot make the Video start. I have added some LOG's to track the progress and it seems that by clicking the play button, nothing changes (except in the Log) and the video doesn't play, and I don't know why. What I get is this frozen screen:

[image]

I have the following code for the Fragment.java:

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    public class FragmentSedinte extends Fragment {
      View v;
      private static final String TAG = "Checking";
      Button btnPlay;
      YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;
      YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;

      public FragmentSedinte() {}

      @Nullable
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sedinte, container, false);
        return v;
      }

      public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        //youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("AIxxxxx",mOnInitializedListener);
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        this.v = view;
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");
        //mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)v.findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);
        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubePlay);
        mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Done initialising");
            youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("tz-Wf9nEFao");
            youTubePlayer.play();

          }
          @Override
          public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Failed initializing");
          }
        };

        btnPlay = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Initializing YouTube");
            //mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YouTubeConfig.getApiKey(),mOnInitializedListener);
            mYouTubePlayerView.initialize("AIxxxxxxxx", mOnInitializedListener);
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

where the Layout has the following code:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns : android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android: id = "@+id/container"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: orientation = "vertical" >

  <fragment
android: id = "@+id/youtubePlay"
android: name = "com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content" / >

  <Button
android: id = "@+id/btnPlay"
android: layout_width = "100dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
android: gravity = "center_vertical|fill_vertical"
android: text = "Play"
android: textAlignment = "center" / >
  </LinearLayout>

  </FrameLayout>
```

When I click on Play, I can see in the Logcat that it is triggered, but it doesn't start the video. In the log I have this:

```
 02 - 27 10: 26: 50.092 17297 - 17320 / Package.recyclerview V / FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
    02 - 27 10: 26: 54.137 17297 - 17297 / Package.recyclerview D / Checking: onClick: Initializing YouTube
    02 - 27 10: 26: 59.422 17297 - 17297 / Package.recyclerview D / Checking: onCreate: Starting.
    02 - 27 10: 27: 02.786 17297 - 17297 / Package.recyclerview D / Checking: onClick: Initializing YouTube
```

Which is clear that the button is triggered, but it seems like it doesn't go to `onInitializationSuccess`. Can anyone please help me figure this one out?

I can add more files if necessary, but I think the problem comes from the first file posted here.

Comment: Thank you @Abhishekc, some of the things in this code are taken from there. Especially in the layout, because I was getting "Error inflating..."

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed the `YouTubePlayerFragment` and `YouTubePlayerView`

Update your code from

```
 mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);
```

TO

```
YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment)getFragmentManager()
             .findFragmentById(R.id.youtubePlay);
```

Change Loading

```
 @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.loadVideo(YoutubeLinkRequest.getYouTubeID(youTubeURL), currentPlaying);
        }
        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just tried, but no success. The same behavior...

Comment: It still shows `Checking: onClick: Initializing`. It seems that it doesn't want to jump to onInitializationSuccess

Comment: is it calling `onInitializationSuccess` or `onInitializationFailure`?

Comment: None of them. It seems like it is stuck in `public void onClick(View view){` For this reason, I have also tried to add a line to play the video directly without the button (see the commented code under `onViewCreated`), and it is the same.

Comment: Updated the answer check it

Comment: Thank you for staying with me on this. The change between `R.id.youtubePlay` and `R.id.youtubeplayerfragment` involves changes in the way the fragment is give in the layout? Or which one is `youtubeplayerfragment`?. Moreover, `YouTubeLinkRequest` doesn't exist in the library :(

Comment: Updated you have to use `youtubePlay`

Comment: Okay. I had to use `(YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)` instead of `(YouTubePlayerFragment)`, otherwise it would not run. Now it gives "       java.lang.NullPointerException" when clicking the button. I will edit the text for the change. `YoutubeLinkRequest` doesn't work, therefore I kept `youTubePlayer.loadVideo("tz-Wf9nEFao");`